# clearcase rpctcp_create: RPC: Remote system error - [WINSOCK] Connection timed out

Tags: clearcase

I am unable to onctact the server from a ClearCase 8 view, with the message:

```
rpctcp_create: RPC: Remote system error - [WINSOCK] Connection timed out
clearlicense: Error: Unable to contact albd_server on host 'ccsrv02'
clearlicense: Error: Cannot contact license server host "ccsrv02".
```

clearlicense returns

```
 Using Windows 7 OS
 All services are running
 Clearcase version 8.0.0.6
```

How would you troubleshoot that error message?

Comment: When executed clearlicense,following issue is seen:                                           - Using Windows 7 OS                                                                                           - All services are running                                                                                       - Clearcase version 8.0.0.6 ...Any clues on this issue?

Comment: Hi harish, don't forget to take the tour http://stackoverflow.com/tour and read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer as well as http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote regarding your previous questions about ClearCase.

Answer (score 0):

Check if all the services are running on the client and the server:

```
Settings -> Control Panel -> ClearCase -> Services
```

Those ClearCase services ahve dependencies (to Remote Procedure Call (RPC) Locator
and/or Remote Procedure Call (RPC)) and all must be running, in order for a client to contact the view/vob and license servers.